# Why the response so slowly when first request to Django server

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

Now I make prediction using TensorFlow inside django. And there is one issue when I test. When Django server is started, and the response from Django server is so slowly when first request, it is hunted by sessison.run. And it is fast when make second, third request, how to fix this issue about first request slowly.

I tried to add some tf app function, but it doesn't work.

```
genfun=get_batch_generator(data_list)
fo = codecs.open("./result", "w","utf-8")
for input_data,y_true in genfun:
    y_pred = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={'text_left:0': input_data['text_left'],'text_right:0': input_data['text_right']})
for y in y_pred:
    fo.write(str(y[1])+"\n")
```

`sess` are defined the outer file when run `python manage.py runserver` command.

```
class NNmodel(object) :
        ins_ = None

        @classmethod
        def instance(cls) :
                cls.ins_ = cls.ins_ if cls.ins_ else NNmodel()
                return cls.ins_

        def __init__(self):
                self.flag_ = False
                self.pred = None
                self.sess = None
        def load(self,nn_model_file) :
                if self.flag_ == True :
                        return
                self.flag_ = True
                gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3)
                self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options,allow_soft_placement = True))
                with tf.gfile.FastGFile(nn_model_file, 'rb') as f:
                        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
                        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
                        self.sess.graph.as_default()
                        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

                # Get graph
                graph = tf.get_default_graph()
                self.pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("dense_9/Softmax:0")
```

The response is so slow when making the first request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the graph and the session are initialized outside the request function, then there is only one explanation: GPU needs warm-up.

So, a solution is to run a dummy prediction as soon as you initialize the session. For example, you can feed some random numbers of the right shape. Just do a

```
sess.run(pred, feed_dict={'text_left:0': np.random.rand(batch_size, sentence_size),'text_right:0': np.random.rand(batch_size, sentence_size)})
```

Comment: it did warm-up.Now i add sess.sun after init ,and the first request is fast

Comment: @davidliu glad to hear it worked ! Don't forget to mark this as an answer by ticking the check-mark next to it. This way, future programmers with the same question can find the answer easily